# How can apropos find emacs?

Tags: editors, apropos

Funny thing is, after 25 years of hearing what apropos can do -- 25 years ago I didn't understand what it can do -- yesterday I just found that it is for making suggestions for what tools or command you can use. Such as:

```
apropos editor
```

and it will show a list that includes `pico` and `vim`.  However, I can't find `emacs` and no matter what I used for the keyboard, `emacs` won't show. Is there a way to actually find it?

(I am using Ubuntu 15.10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apropos` just searches short descriptions and names within the manual page. When you open a manual page, for example `man apropos`:

```
NAME
       apropos - search the manual page names and descriptions
       └──┬──┘   └─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┘
        name                   short description
```

`apropos` searches for a keyword within this part, that each manual page has.

---

The manual page of `emacs` just don't mention the word `editor` in its short description:

```
$ man emacs
[...]
NAME
       emacs - GNU project Emacs
```

Comment: maybe it is the style of Richard Stallman at that time